# Перечислить через запятую в switch значения

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

В VB.NET есть вот такая конструкция:

```
Case Keys.Control Or Keys.D1, Keys.Control Or Keys.NumPad1
```

Т.е через запятую можно перечислить 2 кейза.

Есть ли что-нибудь подобное в C#?

Или подобное в C# записывается так :

```
case Keys.Control | Keys.D1:
case Keys.Control | Keys.NumPad1:
     {
          break;
      }
```

?

Comment: В Java так case Keys.D1: case Keys.NumPad1:  {
          break;
      } Возможно в C# также

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Пишите case блоки один за другим, управление будет передаваться вниз до первого break/return/etc.

```
int i = 0;  
switch (i)  
{  
    case 0:  
    case 1:  
    case 2:  
        // какое-то действие, общее для всех трех вариантов  
        break;  

    case 3:  
    case 4:  
    case 5:  
        // другое общее действие  
        break;  
}
```